# NodeJs - Call API Url Link with another API

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, http, axios

Problem: I'm trying to connect an API url link through another API function.

API Url (Provided by Third Party): `http://garden.home.com:8080/api/GetAllHome`

API Link (Created by me): `http://localhost:3000/town/house`

The API link created by me is just meant to be a API function which will contain the **provided** API url. I'm trying to connect to the API provided thought my function but I'm encountering problems.

I've tried using `http.get` and `axios.get` but I've encountered several problems

**Using http.get**

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND garden.home.com garden.home.com:8080
*"message": "http.get(...).then is not a function"*

```
app.get('/town/house', (req, res, next) => {
    http.get(allHouseUrl)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data.url);
            console.log(response.data.explanation);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
});
```

`const allHouseUrl = {
    host: 'garden.home.com',
    port: 8080,
    path: '/api/GetAllHome'
}`

I tried the online solutions, which was to wrote their url details in an object and call it.

**Using axios.get**

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND garden.home.com garden.home.com:8080

```
app.get('/town/house', (req, res, next) => {
    axios.get("http://garden.home.com:8080/api/GetAllHome")
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data.url);
            console.log(response.data.explanation);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
});
```

My desired results would be to connect to the **provided url link** and be able to pass parameters to it.

I am able to to retrieve the json data from `http://garden.home.com:8080/api/GetAllHome` by using Postman but I am unable to access it through an API function that I created.

Comment: The problem is clear as day. You have an invalid url. There is nothing hosted at `garden.home.com` that is listening for requests on port 8080

Comment: Can you `ping garden.home.com` from where you're running that code? It looks like a DNS error.

Comment: Hi 9000, I'm able to ping it and I am able to to retrieve the json data from `http://garden.home.com:8080/api/GetAllHome` by using Postman.